# How to add some actions when page change happened in JQuery Mobile for iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have created a form page with back button enabled. Now my intention was to reset all input data in the form when back button click or when page appear.

My first target was to add action when back button triggered.

[image: Header back button. Image is added here]

I have written below code to add back button. (data-add-back-btn="true")

```
<div id="xxxxx" data-role="page" data-theme="d" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

Now I want to do some action when back button clicked. I tried to add event listener but no works.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    //written some codes here but it's not triggering when back button clicked                      
}, false);
```

My second try was to add those codes inside below methods.

```
$( ":jqmData(role='page')" ).live( "pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
    // Here I wrote code but no works                                                    
});
```

and

```
$( ":jqmData(role='page')" ).live( "pageshow", function(event) {
 // Here I wrote code but no works    
});
```

Please suggest how to do this. Please understand I can't change implementation. I have to fix it with current scenario and code. I can't change implementation of "back button".

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Where is the page id? For which page you are attaching pagebeforeshow/pageshow events?

Comment: But I have to implement for 23 pages. If I specify page ID then I have to write for 23 pages. Also I wrote all pages in a single HTML file i.e., index.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
const backButton = document.querySelector(".backButton");

backButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  console.log("Back button has been click");
  
});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0em;
}

.navbar{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3em;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="backButton">Back</div>
</div>
```

First i did't know JS have a event called `backbutton` but i'm sure JS have a event called `click`

Comment: You have created your own customize button class. I can't do it right now. Then I need to make huge change in my application. I have to use existing code <div id="xxxxx" data-role="page" data-theme="d" data-add-back-btn="true"> to add button. backbutton events it's not there in JS but in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is do not use a lot of pages in your cordova application just use just one page like index.html then put your all pages inside of it and use show and hide function to view the page that you want to show using div tag. examples below.

```
    <div id="registerPage" style="display:none"> </div>
```

if you want to show that page try

```
$('#registerPage')css("display", "block");
```

and hide all other view by

```
$('#pageid')css("display", "none");
```

and to implement addEventListener to buttons try this. Inside of your `onDeviceReady: function()`

define your all buttons like this

```
$('#yourButtonId').click(fucntionNameHere);
```

and implement your all functions. Tell me if you had any problem with this way I will help you.

Comment: First I want to tell you that the application already made. I can't change anything right now. I have added back button like above. Now I want to reset page on click of back button. If you have any idea for this scenario then please suggest.